HDF5/h5py performance reading datasets
I have millions of images saved in a HDF5 file that I want to read in random order as fast as possible. I compared read time in sequential (alphabetical) vs random order. I found random order time is much higher compared to sequential read time. What can be done to improve random order read performance? The code and profile time line are shown here:
    with h5py.File("/slowdata/caid_2024/GenImage_compressed.h5") as hf:
        keys = list(hf.keys())
        from random import shuffle

        sleep(0.1)

        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            if i == 16:
                break
            np.array(hf[key])
        
        # Random order now
        shuffle(keys)
        sleep(0.1)
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            if i == 16:
                break
            np.array(hf[key])
        sleep(0.1)



It's not like HDF5 can somehow outwit the physics of disk latency and seek times. It would be interesting to see if the IO is considerably worse than similar random reads from a simple binary file. That could indicate some issues with your file usage, e.g. it might be better to store all images as a single large dataset

Multiple processes (HDF5 cannot multithread) can also help hide latency with overlapping IO operations. Also helps with command queueing on modern disks and SSDs

I can't explain why you see such a difference in your profiler. I would not expect a significant difference in I/O performance based on the order datasets are read. To confirm this, I built a simple test to mimic your code and saw very little variation. My code is at the end.
HDF5 datasets are not accessed sequentially, so there's no need advantage to reading in creation order. Besides, dataset names (aka the keys) are returned in alphabetical order, not creation order. In other words, dataset Alpha is returned before Zulu, even if Zulu was created first. So, you can't really control reading in creation order.
That said, h5py/HDF5 I/O performance is controlled by a number of factors:

The most significant factor when working with very large datasets is chunked I/O (if it's enabled, and if the chunk size is set appropriately).
Another factor is size and number of data blocks read. Reading a lot of small data blocks is slower that reading the same amount of data as a few large data blocks.
Compression also slows I/O performance.

Also, I noticed you used np.array(hf[key]) to create a NumPy array from the dataset. The preferred method is hf[key][()]. I benchmarked both methods. The preferred way is slightly faster (6-10%), but shows the same random vs alphabetical behavior.
Performance statistics for my test code at the end. Note that random read order is actually a little faster than alphabetical. This could be due to cached I/O. I need more details about your file and datasets to diagnose why you see a difference.
dataset shape = 256, 256, 10_000
H5 size: 39 GB

WITHOUT CHUNKED I/O
Time to create file: 373.49 sec

read peformance:
As written using np.array(hfr[key]):
Time to read datasets alphabetically: 407.66 sec
Time to read datasets randomly: 355.97 sec

Modified to use hfr[key][()]:
Time to read datasets alphabetically: 360.67 sec
Time to read datasets randomly: 333.69 sec

Code below.
img_w, img_h, img_cnt = 256, 256, 10_000
ds_cnt = 16
start = time.time()
with h5py.File("SO_78500597.h5","w") as hfw:
    for i in range(ds_cnt):
        rgb_val = int((255/ds_cnt)*i)
        hfw.create_dataset(f'image_{i:02}', data=np.full((img_w, img_h, img_cnt), rgb_val, dtype=int))
print(f"Time to create file: {(time.time()-start):.2f} sec")   

with h5py.File("SO_78500597.h5") as hfr:
        keys = list(hfr.keys())
        print(keys)
        from random import shuffle

        start = time.time()
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            if i == 16:
                break
            #np.array(hfr[key])
            arr = hfr[key][()]
        print(f"Time to read datasets alphabetically: {(time.time()-start):.2f} sec")    
        
        # Random order now
        shuffle(keys)
        start = time.time()
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            if i == 16:
                break
            #np.array(hfr[key])
            arr = hfr[key][()]
        print(f"Time to read datasets randomly: {(time.time()-start):.2f} sec")    

